# Filtro en JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estoy Utilizando el plugin de jquery de galeria el problema es cuando no filtro aparecen todas las imagenes y yo quiero que sin presionar un filtro aparezcan solo las que yo marque como "all"

este es mi codigo HTML

```
        <div class="categories">

            <ul class="cat">
                <li class="pull-left"><h4>Galeria</h4></li>
                <li class="pull-right">
                    <ol class="type">
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".all" class="active">TODOS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".web">Diseño Mobiliario</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".photography">Llave en Mano</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".app" >Locales Comerciales</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".web">Organización de Espacios</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".branding" >Conferencias</a></li>

                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="lightbox" class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 all branding">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="hover-bg">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="hover-text">
                                <h4>Verónica Chapa</h4>
                                <small>Conferencias</small>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/portfolio/01.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 photography app">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="hover-bg">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="hover-text">
                                <h4>Verónica Chapa</h4>
                                <small>Llave en Mano</small>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/portfolio/02.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 branding">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="hover-bg">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="hover-text">
                                <h4>Verónica Chapa</h4>
                                <small>Conferencias</small>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/portfolio/03.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 branding">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="hover-bg">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="hover-text">
                                <h4>Verónica Chapa</h4>
                                <small>Conferencias</small>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/portfolio/04.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 web">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="hover-bg">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="hover-text">
                                <h4>Verónica Chapa</h4>
                                <small>Diseño Mobiliario</small>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/portfolio/05.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 app">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="hover-bg">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="hover-text">
                                <h4>Verónica Chapa</h4>
                                <small>Locales Comerciales</small>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/portfolio/06.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 photography web">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="hover-bg">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="hover-text">
                                <h4>Verónica Chapa</h4>
                                <small>Llave en Mano</small>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/portfolio/07.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 web">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="hover-bg">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="hover-text">
                                <h4>Verónica Chapa</h4>
                                <small>Diseño Mobiliario</small>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/portfolio/08.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 web ">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <div class="hover-bg">
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="hover-text">
                                <h4>Verónica Chapa</h4>
                                <small>Diseño Mobiliario</small>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </div>
                            <img src="img/portfolio/08.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Y este el Jquery

```
    _filter : function( $atoms ) {

 var filter = this.options.filter === '' ? 'all' : this.options.filter;

  if ( !filter ) {
    return $atoms;
  }
     var hiddenClass    = this.options.hiddenClass,
      hiddenSelector = '.' + hiddenClass,
      $hiddenAtoms   = $atoms.filter( hiddenSelector ),
      $atomsToShow   = $hiddenAtoms;


  if ( filter !== 'all' ) {
    $atomsToShow = $hiddenAtoms.filter( filter );
    var $atomsToHide = $atoms.not( hiddenSelector ).not( filter ).addClass( hiddenClass );
    this.styleQueue.push({ $el: $atomsToHide, style: this.options.hiddenStyle });
 }

  this.styleQueue.push({ $el: $atomsToShow, style: this.options.visibleStyle });
  $atomsToShow.removeClass( hiddenClass );

  return $atoms.filter( filter );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

solo nos muestras la parte del filtro, pero no nos muestras el evento lanzador que activa ese filtro.

es decir algo como

```
$('ul > li').on('click', function(){
 ///bla bla
});
```

Al respuesta es que al terminar la carga de la página, vaya a ese evento activandolo como si se le hubiese dado click.

Suponiendo mi evento anterior, así se veria al terminar la carga.

```
$(function(){
   $('ul > li').trigger('click');
});
```

Esto activaría una simulación de "click" en tu botón "all", al cargar la página sin presionarlo realmente.

Más información en:

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

y en todos los eventos disponible para moverle:

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/